# Vue dynamic import is being imported even if it is never used

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am building a vue plugin called vue-scan-field. At the previous version (0.1.2) the plugin only supported vuetify. Now I want to also add quasar to this plugin. So what I have decided to do is use dynamic imports for the components. For example the quasar file looks like this:

```
export default {
  components: {
    scan_text_field: () => import('quasar/src/components/input/QInput'),
    scan_textarea: () => import('quasar/src/components/input/QInput'),
    scan_checkbox: () => import('quasar/src/components/checkbox/QCheckbox'),
    scan_select: () => import('quasar/src/components/select/QSelect')
  },
  ...
}
```

And I also have this for vuetify:

```
export default {
  components: {
    scan_text_field: () => import('vuetify/lib/components/VTextField'),
    scan_textarea: () => import('vuetify/lib/components/VTextarea'),
    scan_checkbox: () => import('vuetify/lib/components/VCheckbox/VCheckbox'),
    scan_select: () => import('vuetify/lib/components/VAutocomplete'),
  },
  ...
}
```

Now download the module from npm and run my quasar project I get these errors:

```
These dependencies were not found:

* vuetify/lib/components in ./node_modules/vue-scan-field/dist/vue-scan-field.esm.js
* vuetify/lib/components/VAutocomplete in ./node_modules/vue-scan-field/dist/vue-scan-field.esm.js
* vuetify/lib/components/VCheckbox/VCheckbox in ./node_modules/vue-scan-field/dist/vue-scan-field.esm.js
* vuetify/lib/components/VTextField in ./node_modules/vue-scan-field/dist/vue-scan-field.esm.js
* vuetify/lib/components/VTextarea in ./node_modules/vue-scan-field/dist/vue-scan-field.esm.js
```

Now this can be because maybe my compiler imports the components on build. I don't know if I can safely disable this function (I don't think so). Is there any way to fix this?

NPM Package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-scan-field

Github page: https://github.com/jessielaf/vue-scan-field

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic components in Webpack (and in general) work because bundler at build time prepares js files (with component code) which are at runtime loaded (or not ...depending on logic) by the app. Bundler can not execute your code and evaluate the logic which decides which component should be loaded. It must prepare the budle for all possible outcomes.

So yes, of course your bundler looks for and bundle all the files even they are used in dynamic import.

I do not know exactly how to set up Rollup correctly but I'm pretty sure you don't want to include **any** Vuetify/Quasar code as part of your library. Such code would be duplicate and possibly from different version of the framework the user of your library is already using! So instead of using string configuration (`framework: 'vuetify'`), leave it to your users to pass the component mapping (and maybe add sample to your docs)...

```js
// dynamic
Vue.use(ScanField, { components: {
    scan_text_field: () => import('quasar/src/components/input/QInput'),
    scan_textarea: () => import('quasar/src/components/input/QInput'),
    scan_checkbox: () => import('quasar/src/components/checkbox/QCheckbox'),
    scan_select: () => import('quasar/src/components/select/QSelect'),
    scan_date: () => null
}})

// static
import QInput from 'quasar/src/components/input/QInput'

Vue.use(ScanField, { components: {
    scan_text_field: QInput,
    ...  
}})
```

**Alternative** solution is to use normal (not dynamic) imports, but configure Rollup so that both Vuetify and Quasar are treated as **peerDependencies** (dependency your lib requires but the user is responsible to add/install it into his project) - see [the docs](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#peer-dependencies)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately this is also my conclusion. There is some custom mapping of the attributes per framework I need to do so it is unfortunate that this is the case. About the peer dependency. I don't want to require my end users to install a whole other framework. The last thing I tried was a [dynamic async import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67502397/quasar-importing-dynamic-components-imported-without-being-used). But it did not work. Although vue 3 has a function `defineAsyncComponent` so maybe I can leverage this in the future.